# Do I need to install Tomcat *in addition to* the one provided with Eclipse WTP in order to run in DEBUG from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am trying to follow the [Spring MVC Example](https://www.journaldev.com/14476/spring-mvc-example) from JournalDev.

It builds and runs fine from Eclipse (which includes the WTP plugin):

```
Jul 30, 2021 2:04:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 30, 2021 2:04:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Jul 30, 2021 2:04:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Jul 30, 2021 2:04:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jul 30, 2021 2:04:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

But when I try to access it from a browser, I get the following "HTTP Status 404" error:

[image]

This tells me that Apache Tomcat is somehow running but something is misconfigured (I get the same error for http://localhost:8080/manager/html)

(running this example webapp on a standalone Tomcat works fine)

What do I need to do to run this webapp (http://localhost:8080/spring-mvc-example/) directly from Eclipse DEBUG perspective?

Comment: Double check the context path under which your application is deployed. By default it is your Eclipse project's name. BTW: Tomcat 7.0 reached end-of-life, you should use Tomcat 8.5 or 9.0.

Comment: `/manager/html` is usually not installed on Eclipse since Eclipse itself is kind of doing that job.

Comment: "running this example webapp on a standalone Tomcat works fine" because it's deployed there. Is your project deployed to the instance you're launching from Eclipse, and as spring-mvc-example, and with a welcome page to service that URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is No. No need to install another instance of Tomcat if the [Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/index.html) is used.

There is a challenge, however, in setting the context path correctly and deploying the WAR artifact to `target/tomcat/web` since by default it deploys to `target`.

https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-root-application is a good resource for configuring the context path on a standalone Tomcat installation (i.e. one that is not destroyed and reinstalled upon debug build & run) but for a Tomcat plugin environment the following resource is more helpful: https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/usage.html